# Python, tengo un error cuando quiero llamar a un diccionario

Tags: python, sql, input, datos, registro

Necesito hacer 2 funciones, una que cargue los datos y la otra función que muestre los datos guardados. Ésta misma debe devolver un diccionario, el problema está en que no logro vincular el código de la primera función con la segunda.

```
def RegistroAlumnos():
    
     while True:
            
            alumnos_cantidad=int(input("Ingresa la cant de alumnos a ingresar: "))

            for i in range(0,alumnos_cantidad):
                    alumnos = {
                    'Nombre': None, 
                    'Apellido': None,
                    'Nota': None,
                    }

                    nombre=input('Ingrese el nombre del alumno: ')
                    apellido=input('Ingrese el apellido del alumno: ')
                    nota=int(input('Ingrese la nota que se saco: '))
                    
                    if nota == 0:
                        print('Reprobado')
                    elif nota<6:
                        print('Recupera')
                    elif nota>=7:
                        print('Aprueba, pasa de año')
                    return alumnos
      
def ConsultaAlumnos():
    
       while True:
        # alumno={'nombre':nombre,'apellido':apellido,'nota':nota}

        if len(alumno)==0:
            print('La lista esta vacia')
        else:
            for i in alumno.items():
               print(i) 

def Menu():

 while True:          

            print("1. Ingresar Nuevos Registros")
            print("2. Consultar Registros")
            print("3. Salir del programa")
            opcion= input('Ingrese una opcion: ')
            if opcion == '1':
                RegistroAlumnos()
            elif opcion == '2':
                ConsultaAlumnos()

menu()
```

Comment: Buen día, no es muy claro lo que deseas hacer ni el problema que tienes. ¿El problema es que no puedes consultar a los alumnos registrados? Por otra parte, cada iteración del for creas un nuevo diccionario `alumnos` y además no le agregas ningún valor por lo que siempre te va a devolver `{'Nombre': None, 'Apellido': None, 'Nota': None}`

Comment: Si, la funcion ConsultaAlumnos me tiene que traer los datos del diccionario creado en la funcion RegistroAlumnos pero no logro hacer que funcione

Comment: Tienes varios problemas en las funciones, como comenté, en primer lugar no estás agregando ningún dato al diccionario. ¿Qué sucede si se agrega dos veces al mismo alumno? Requieres validación o eso no importa? Si los alumnos van a agregarse desde un función, consultarse desde otra función diferente y tal vez en un futuro eliminarse desde una tercera función, tal vez podrías utilizar una variable global.

Comment: Tengo un error: pon el error en la pregunta

Comment: En lugar de escribir "solucionado", pon _como respuesta_ cómo resolviste tu problema. Recuerda que [es.so] es un sitio de **preguntas y respuestas**. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además, pon en la pregunta cuál era el error que estabas teniendo. Las preguntas y sus respuestas deben ser útiles _para todos_, no solo para el autor de la pregunta. Lee [ask] y [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Debes definir el diccionario `Alumnos` fuera de las funciones.

Además, observa que en la función `ConsultaAlumnos` llamas al diccionario `alumno` mientras que en la función `RegistroAlumnos` defines el diccionario `alumnos`.

Con esos dos cambios se solucionará el problema.

Comment: Mil gracias! Ya lo solucione, me falto hacer eso, fue lo primero que hice pero al darme error lo descarte y resulto siendo que el error era otra cosa y eso estaba bien

Comment: @jazmindev si esta respuesta te sirvió para solucionar el problema, considera marcarla como aceptada y, opcionalmente, darle un voto positivo.